# Change PHP binary being used by localhost

Tags: php, macos

I had been PHP version using 5.5.11 on my Mac and have some modules installed. They took quite a lot of tinkering around to get working. I have my OSX already using this version by using a PATH in my ./~profile. After I installed Yosemite though my localhost now runs PHP 5.5.14, which doesn't have the modules installed. How do I get my localhost to use my other PHP installation?

I have tried in httpd.conf `LoadModule php5_module \path\to\other\binary`. I restarted Apache but it wouldn't load my page then. So i'm unsure of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so easy, in my mind the easy way should be to install a new version with the modules you need 
If you are lucky all modules you need are present in the package from
http://php-osx.liip.ch/

The hard way : install manually the php and all modules ...